# SQL query select row when match is made, select other row when match is not made

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, one-to-many

I have 2 tables:

> attribuut
>
> attribuutvalue

They have a one-to-many relationship.
An attribuut can have multiple attribuutvalues.
These attribuutvalues contain states.

Now I want a query which gives me back the latest attribuutvalue from an attribuut, which has:
state **3** or state **6**.

Then i hit my problem:
When an attribuut contains an attribuutvalue with state **4**, only the latest attribuutvalue with state **3** should be shown.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM attribuut as att
LEFT JOIN attribuutvalue as value ON (value.attribuuthead = att.displayid)
WHERE value.status = 3 OR (value.status = 6 
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM attribuutvalue as value2 WHERE value2.valueid = value.valueid AND value2.status = 4)) 
ORDER BY valueid DESC
```

However this gives me not the resultset i want. There are still attribuutvalues with state 4 shown.
And it doesnt give me only the last record in the list...

Comment: This is fairly confusing, I think you need to provide some sample data and desired output to clarify it, please!

Answer (score 1):

First problem you have is in your `NOT EXISTS` sub-query. You should have joined on `attribuuthead` and not `valueid` (which I presume is unique key on that table)

Second you are missing a mechanism to filter only one value per `attribuuthead`. [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) can achieve that.

So fixed query could look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY attribuuthead ORDER BY valueid DESC) RN
    FROM dbo.attribuutvalue v
    WHERE STATUS = 3 OR (Status = 6 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM attribuutvalue v2 WHERE v2.attribuuthead = v.attribuuthead AND v2.STATUS = 4))
) x
INNER JOIN attribuut a ON x.attribuuthead = a.displayid
WHERE x.RN = 1
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3796d/1)**